# Does tableFunction support using parameters as condtions?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to use a `tableFunction` to extrapolate some values. If I input the condition as a static value it works fine.

[image]

However, when I use a parameter as a condition the outcome becomes NAN. The Idea here, is that in a population of agents, I am trying to get the agent specific values from the database into the table function using the parameter

```
v3Code
```

[image]

Finally, the data looks something like this:

[image]

It there a limitation here, workaround or Anything else I missed here ?
Thanks_InAdvance();

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on how you are creating your agents and setting the v3Code parameter. I have used this before and I was loading my agents from database and set parameters from database and it worked fine. However, in another case, I was setting the parameter AFTER creating the agent which resulted in similar situation.

The workaround I suggest is to create another population,called functionHolders, with agents that only have the table function and v3Code parameter. Then, in main startup populate all possible functionHolders (let's say v3Code ranges from 0 to 4).

Main startup code:
`for(int i=0;i<5;i++){add_functionHolder(i);}`

and when you need to use the function:
`main.functionHolders.get(v3Code).tabelFunction_area_of_issue()`

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I am setting everything from a database, and it is just frustrating to have this problem. I appreciate your suggestion but, it will consume more memory, which is something I am trying to avoid as much as possible. If there is no direct solution, I guess my approach would be to extrapolate the data outside AnyLogic and create parameters with SQL queries from the database.

Comment: I don't know what would be the problem with loading the condition then because a similar function worked in my project. However, regarding the memory, I think it would be more memory efficient if you create the function holders especially if the number of possible v3Code values are significantly less than the number of agents you have.

Comment: I just noticed that it might be a datatype issue. Is v3Code parameter the same type as the column you are filtering?